# OpenGL via xrdp Remote Desktop

Tags: opengl, xrdp

I have a CentOS 7.6 server where I login using xrdp, which works fine. However, I have one particular software where the screen stays black. I found that this is an OpenGL issue. The screen is visible as long as the window is scrolled or moved, but noth otherwise.
I tried to diagnose OpenGL problems using `glxgears` and `glxspheres`, but these both works fine.
I also connected via `ssh -X` to the server from another computer (where I am logged in via RDP!) and let the particular program run using `vglrun`, but this didn't work at all - it tells me `cannot open display :0`.
How should I proceed to find the problem, and is it in general possible to use OpenGL via RDP?